# Polar Plot in Python - Repeat of peak looks like kaleidoscope

Tags: matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to plot a polar plot in matplotlib. When I use normal, rectangular coordinates, I get the plot I want:

```
dir_mesh, f_mesh = np.meshgrid(dir,freq[indsf])

pl.pcolor(dir_mesh,f_mesh,S1)
```

correct plot

[image]

If I use a polar projection, multiple peaks are present!

```
ax = pl.subplot(111,projection = "polar")
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
c = ax.pcolor(dir_mesh,f_mesh,S1)
```

kaleidoscope polar plot (wrong)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The units of a polar plot are radiants. If you supply your data in degrees, ranging from 0 to 360, the data will revolve 57 times around the polar plot and  the result will look something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

theta = np.arange(0,361,10)
r = np.linspace(0.,0.8,len(theta) )
ax = plt.subplot(111,projection = "polar")

ax.plot(theta,r)
plt.show()
```

[image]

In order to get the desired result you need to scale your theta data to the range between 0 and 2π.

e.g. `theta = theta/180.*np.pi`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

theta = np.arange(0,361,10)
theta = theta/180.*np.pi
r = np.linspace(0.,0.8,len(theta) )
ax = plt.subplot(111,projection = "polar")

ax.plot(theta,r)

plt.show()
```

[image]